# What's the symbolic definition of the maximum value of a domain?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Lets say we have a domain S

Maximum value of domain S = {S | ? ? ? ? ? ? }

How could one define the possible maximum value of a set of values, symbolically?

Comment: What do you mean by $S = \{S \mid \ldots\}$?

Comment: ignore that, its just a way of expressing a relationship between S and its max value, which I don't know how to represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is an (ordered) set, we write the maximum value of $S$ as $$\max S.$$ If $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots, s_n\}$, we could also write $\max S$ as $$\max(s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots, s_n)$$ or as $\max_i s_i$.

Comment: Is there a reason you talk about _ordered_ sets?  If $S$ is a set (which is finite, or has a maximum for some other reason) then $\max S$ denotes the maximum element.  So if $S = \{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ then we could write $\max S$ as $\max \{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ (although perhaps the notation with parentheses is more common in this case.)

Comment: @TrevorWilson My thought was that if $A$ is an arbitrary set, $\max A$ doesn't make sense unless we specify some sort of order on $A$.

Comment: Oh, of course!  Silly me.  I took it for granted that $S$ was a subset of some linear ordering, and I thought you were saying that $S$ was a tuple (probably because of the parentheses instead of curly braces.)  Your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: I have a tricky question. Represent symbolically the maximum integer possible.

Comment: So you have a set $S$ containing both integers and non-integers and you want to represent the maximum integer? I think you could write $\max\{s \in S\ |\ s \in \mathbb Z\}$. Or if you don't like how this looks, define $T = \{s \in S\ |\ s \in \mathbb Z\}$ and write $\max T$.

Comment: What about this, using a statement:

For all y ∈ Z, there exist an s, s > y, by that statement max = s

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. Do none of the above suggestions work? Do you mean "if there exists an integer $s \in S$ such that $s \geq y$ for all integers $y \in S$, then $s$ is the maximum integer in $S$"? This is true, and you could define $s$ in that way, but that's no different that writing $s = \max\{x \in S\ |\ x \in \mathbb Z\}$.